# Reference Request - Dynamic Optimization with More Than One State Variable

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics, dynamic-optimization

I would like to understand how to solve dynamic optimization problems involving more than one state variable and state equation (to apply to long-term economic models with more than one capital good).  Searching the web I found [this chapter](http://www.peterthompson.gatech.edu/uploads/images/Teaching/modeling_chapter2.pdf) which seems helpful.

Does anyone know which book the chapter is from (it seems unlikely that it's by Peter Thompson whose website it's on as he lists his specialisms as strategy and innovation)?

Any other recommendations on this topic would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Adam: If you go to the link below and click on teaching and then dynamic modelling, it does sound like it's his book but incomplete. Definitely seems like a well written book. thanks for pointing out because optimal control is on my list of "things to understand someday".   http://www.peterthompson.gatech.edu/

Comment: I think Walsh's book has good D.O. problems that you can solve using Belmans. I think it has a nice solutions manual also.

Comment: @markleeds  Yes, I can see now it's his incomplete book - thank you.

Comment: looks pretty good though even incomplete. all the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by mark leeds, the chapter appears to be part of an incomplete text by Peter Thompson - see [here](http://www.peterthompson.gatech.edu/index.php?page=dynamic-modeling).